# Что за конструкция raise from в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, python-faq

Иногда, я натыкаюсь на конструкцию вида:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError from e
```

Или даже такую:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception:
    raise ValueError from None
```

Что это, и для чего используется?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141991/discussion-on-question-by-----raise-from--python).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Конструкция `raise from` в языке `Python` используется для того, чтобы сформировать дополнительный контекст (цепочку возникновения) исключения.

Синтаксис этой конструкции следующий: `raise <ExceptionType> from <cause>`

---

### Как это работает:

У каждого исключения есть магические атрибуты: `__context__` и `__cause__`, которые содержат в себе контекст возникновения исключения, по умолчанию они всегда инициализируются значением `None`, это можно наглядно увидеть:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__context__)  # None
    print(e.__cause__)    # None
```

Но в ряде случаев данные из этих атрибутов будут использованы для вывода дополнительного контекста ошибки.

---

### Расскажу об этом подробнее:

1. Если при обработке (`except`) одного исключения вызывается другое исключение, то используется атрибут `__context__`, он будет содержать ссылку на то исключение, которое возникло **первым**.

Убедимся в этом:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError
except TypeError as e:
    print(repr(e.__context__))  # ValueError()
```

2. В случае же, когда исключение вызывается при помощи конструкции `raise from` используется атрибут `__cause__`, значением которого становится ссылка на то исключение, которое находится после оператора `from` (**причина исключения**):

Это тоже можно увидеть:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError from IndexError
except TypeError as e:
    print(repr(e.__cause__))  # IndexError()
```

Так как эти атрибуты магические, то вся работа происходит с ними "под капотом", и в действительности запись:

```
raise Exception from ValueError
```

Полностью аналогична следующей последовательности действий:

```
e = Exception()
e.__cause__ = ValueError()
raise e
```

---

Весь дополнительный контекст исключения, который содержат в себе эти атрибуты, конечный пользователь увидит в специфичных ошибках, на которые мы сейчас посмотрим:

**Случай 1**:

Вызов одного исключения, во время обработки другого исключения (контекст, который содержит в себе атрибут `__context__`):

При запуске кода:

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    raise TypeError
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

В тексте ошибки можно заметить следующую строку:

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

Таким образом, отображается весь необходимый контекст: изначально обрабатывалось исключение `ValueError` и во время его обработки возникло другое исключение `TypeError`.

---

**Случай 2**:

При использовании конструкции `raise from` (контекст, который содержит в себе атрибут `__cause__`):

Запуск кода:

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    raise TypeError from e
```

Вызывает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\random-from-sv\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\random-from-sv\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise TypeError from e
TypeError
```

В этой ситуации текст ошибки уже другой, и мы можем наблюдать пояснение о **причине** исключения:

**The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:**

Благодаря чему мы понимаем, что исключение `ValueError`, которое было выброшено, возникло по причине другого исключения `TypeError`.

---

### raise from None

Однако, что же это за конструкция `raise from None`?

Ведь не имеет смысла явно указывать пользователю, что исключение произошло без причины.

В чем тогда будет отличие от обычного вызова `raise`, когда значение `__cause__` инициализируется `None`?

На самом деле, эта конструкция применяется для того, чтобы **скрыть** (подавить) остальной контекст исключения.

Посмотрим на код ниже:

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    raise TypeError from None
```

При его запуске мы увидим уже совсем другую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise TypeError from None
TypeError
```

В которой не содержится никакой информации об исходном исключении `ValueError` - оно было скрыто.

### Из-за чего так произошло?

Дело в том, что при любой перезаписи атрибута `__cause__` (даже значением `None`):

```
e.__cause__ = None
```

Происходит дополнительное действие:

```
e.__suppress_context__ = True
```

Этот магический атрибут `__suppress_context__` отвечает за то, попадет ли в итоговый вывод значение `__context__`.

В связи с чем, контекст всегда дополняется только одним значением - это либо значение атрибута `__context__`, либо, в случае, если была использована конструкция `raise from`, значение атрибута `__cause__`.

В примере кода выше, при вызове конструкции `raise TypeError from None`, несмотря на то, что значение `__context__` содержало ссылку на исключение `ValueError`, которое было самым первым в цепочке, оно было проигнорировано, поскольку перезапись атрибута `__cause__` (оператором `from None`) установила `__suppress_context__` в значение `True`.

---

### Итоги

Обобщив все вышесказанное мы можем понять, что:

- Атрибут **`__cause__`** - содержит в себе прямую ссылку на то исключение, **по причине** которого оно возникло (from **cause**).
- Атрибут **`__context__`** - используется при множественном вызове исключений и содержит в себе прямую ссылку на то исключение, которое **возникло первым**.
- Атрибут **`__suppress_context__`** - отвечает за подавление значения `__context__` и используется в конструкции `raise from`.

И если говорить на более глобальном уровне, который виден при запуске кода:

- Конструкция `raise <ExceptionType> from <cause>` используется для того, чтобы **сохранить** дополнительный контекст исключения.
- Конструкция `raise <ExceptionType> from None` используется для того, чтобы показать только **последнее** исключение, и **скрыть** весь остальной контекст.

---

Дополнительно, можно почитать [официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) на этот счет.

Comment: Кст, а `raise <ExceptionType> from None` не будет тем же, что `raise <ExceptionType>`?

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, отличный вопрос! зависит от ситуации, если выбрасывать только одно это исключение и больше ничего не делать, то ответ - да, это то же самое, вывод не изменится,  потому что `__context__` ничего не будет содержать и подавлять при помощи `__suppress_context__` нЕчего, ну, а если этот вызов будет уже вторым в цепочке, то, как и в примере, он заблокирует показ того исключения, которое содержит `__context__` (первого в цепочке) и вывод будет отличаться